# Entity Framework Slow AddRange Insert to DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am implementing a Database First Entity Framework 6.1 to insert about 2000 master/detail collections to SQL server db. Each collection has about two to three objects. So the the total number or records to be inserted is ~5000. The transaction takes about two to three minutes which is very slow. I am using the below code:

```cs
    public class Collection
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        ...

        public List<DetailCol> Details{ get; set; } 
    }


    public class DetailCol
    {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public decimal Lvl { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    var MyCollections = new List<Collection>();
    
    // Do population of collection and try to insert to db

    using (var db = new MyContext(ConnectionString)
    {
        // Speed up insert
        db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    
        // Add new entries to master and details
        db.MyCollections.AddRange(MyCollections);
    
        // Update db
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Can someone give a hint why this is happening and how to improve that?

Comment: For ~5000 records 2-3 minutes seems to be in the ballpark.  Using `SqlBulkCopy` can improve speed dramatically.  DbContext iterates over the records and inserts them one at a time.

Comment: 30 rows per seconds is certainly not "in the ballpark". That is extremely slow. Use SQL Server Profiler to capture some execution plans for those inserts. You'll probably find some slow statements there. What's the CPU usage of the client and server during the inserts?

Comment: I've used in the past SqlBulkCopy for inserting ~100K records (but not master detail) however I was surprised that even for such small number of records EF still struggling.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me. Doesn't seem to be SQL server issue - inserts execute in miliseconds, but for ~1400 records it takes about a minute, which is awful. And these aren't master/detail records. I've tried doing ToArrays, messing with the dbRepo.Configuration, even using new instances of the repository... nothing... Also not a network issue

Comment: Edit: have you tried running from compiled binaries? It runs ~100x faster this way in my case.

Answer (score 4):

I just went through this same thing, and AddRange() takes minutes to add just 1200 records in EF 6.1 since it is doing INSERTS one at a time when you look at the profiler, so BulkCopy is going to be your fastest option.  The good news is for basic Table inserts you can use an extension called EntityFramework.BulkInsert by installing this nuget package:  [EFBulkInsert](https://entityframework-extensions.net/download)

Add: using EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions;
Then do something like this:

```
var options = new BulkInsertOptions();
options.BatchSize = 1000; // Default is 5000
efContext.BulkInsert<MyObject>(myList, options);
efContext.SaveChanges();
```

I went from minutes to 2-3 seconds, and this was even from my computer to an Azure SQL Database.

Comment: I'm on Azure SQL as well but I get  `Global temp objects are not supported in this version of SQL Server.` each time I call a bulk insert... Not sure how you managed.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to update table data using bulk insert from nuget Extensions.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Bulk

```
public async Task Execute(IList<TDest> outRows ,CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            var mapping = _destCtx.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TDest)).Relational();
            var strategy = _destCtx.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
            await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
            {
                using (var tran = _destCtx.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //var dest = _destCtx.Set<TDest>();
                        //dest.RemoveRange(dest);
                        await _destCtx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync((string)$"TRUNCATE TABLE {mapping.Schema}.{mapping.TableName}");
                        //await _destCtx.BulkDeleteAsync(dest, null, stoppingToken);
                        //dest.AddRange(outRows);
                        await _destCtx.BulkInsertAsync(outRows, null, stoppingToken);

                        //await _destCtx.SaveChangesAsync(stoppingToken);

                        tran.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        tran.Rollback();
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```